# Java JButton ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have multiple JButtons in my app. When clicking the buttons with mouse, the correct message is being displayed. But when I try to select one of the buttons upon key press, it shows the first value i.e. the value of the buttons don't change. I want to be able to select multiple buttons upon key press of 'C' on the keyboard.Below is the code:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {

                        String text = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
                    }
                }
            };

             for (int i = 1; i < button.length; i++) {

                 button[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
                 button[i].addActionListener(listener);

                 panel11.add(button[i]);
                 _targetItems.addFirst(button[i]); // target items is a linked list

                }
```

Comment: What did you tried to catch the key 'C' pressed event ? Is it the only listener you have on your buttons ?

Comment: Yes I only have key 'C' as a listener in my program

Comment: @user3668862 I posted a answer, but it may not be exactly what you're looking for. Could you add the code you're using to listen for key presses?

Comment: I don't see anything to catch the key pressed event here. Did you implement a KeyListener class ?

Comment: Hint: button is **bad** name for something that contains **multiple** things. Whats wrong with calling it button**s** instead? Then you only use _ for SOME_CONSTANT; but not for any other name. Finally: what about buttons[0] - that element in your array isn't used?

Comment: @user3668862 could you also clarify what you're trying to do with a single key press? Do you want to press buttons all at the same time? Do you want to only press a very select amount of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single key listener object. Then attach it to all your buttons.

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListner {
     //Override the specific action you want here
     ...
}

button[0].addKeyListener(keyListener); //reuse the same listener for your buttons
...
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html